# How to merge Docker Compose in one image?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to host a Docker Compose file via Google Cloud Run but for that I can only choose one image. So my idea was to merge it into one image. I know it's not exactly the best way to do it but I don't have time to learn Kubernetes.
Thank you!

Comment: There's no way to merge multiple Docker images together.  If you controlled every image's Dockerfile then you could in principle build a single image that contained every component in it, but that's not usually an encouraged approach.